# in_array Not Working inside Function

Tags: php, arrays, function

An array variable `$selected_locations` contains a value `TH` and a string variable `$my_location` is set to `'TH'`.

I verified this using:

```
<?php
$selected_locations = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
print_r($selected_locations);
$user_location = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
$my_location = $user_location->country->isoCode;
echo $my_location;
?>
```

However, the line

```
if( in_array($user_country_code, $selected_locations, true ) )
        $visible = false;
```

in the function below isn't working.

```
function visibility_check( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    $user_location = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $user_country_code = $user_location->country->isoCode;
    $selected_locations = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
    $hidden_items = array();
    foreach( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $item_parent = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true );
        if( in_array($user_country_code, $selected_locations, true ) )
            $visible = false;
        else
            $visible = true;
        if( ! $visible || isset( $hidden_items[$item_parent] ) ) { // also hide the children of unvisible items
            unset( $items[$key] );
            $hidden_items[$item->ID] = '1';
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

If I assign `TH` to the array variable `$selected_locations` manually, it works.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I just realized the array is returning data in the function below `Array ( [0] => 'TH' )`, but is returning empty in the function above. `Array ( [0] => )`

```
function option( $fields, $item_id ) {
ob_start(); ?>
    <p class="field-visibility description description-wide">
        <label for="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
            <?php _e('Enter country code(s) separated by commas') ?>:
            <input
            type="text" 
            class="widefat code" 
            id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" 
            name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" 
            value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ) ); ?>" /></br>
            <input
            type="radio"
            id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id;?>"
            name="menu-item-show-hide[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" 
            value="hide" <?php checked( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'hide_show', true ), 'hide', true ); ?>
            />Hide from these locations.</br>
            <input
            type="radio"
            id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>"
            name="menu-item-show-hide[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]"
            value="show" <?php checked( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'hide_show', true ), 'show', true ); ?>
            />Only show to these locations.</br>
            <?php
            $locations_string = esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ) ); 
            $locations_array = explode(',', $locations_string);
            $locations_array_trimmed = array_map('trim', $locations_array);
            print_r($locations_array_trimmed);
            $user_location = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
            $user_country_code = $user_location->country->isoCode;
            echo $user_country_code;
            ?>
        </label>
    </p>
<?php
$fields[] = ob_get_clean();
return $fields;
}
```

Comment: can you show how values are stored in $selected_locations ?

Comment: add result of `var_dump($selected_locations)`

Comment: var_dump outputs = string(2) "TH"

Comment: it seems that, you stored string value in `$selected_locations`, you should store values in array form like `$selected_locations = ['TH', 'TD', 'TR']`, after that `in_array()` function will work, because `in_array` search values in given array

Comment: Ok, I changed it to an array but it's still not working. It now shows up as Array ( [0] => TH )

Comment: try after removing third parameter i.e. `true` in `in_array` function

Comment: No change after removing true.

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring my variables out of scope. Rearranging things a bit fixed it.

```
function visibility_check( $items, $menu, $args ) {
$hidden_items = array();
foreach( $items as $key => $item ) {
    $user_location = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $user_country_code = $user_location->country->isoCode;
    $selected_locations = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
    $item_parent = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true );
    if( in_array($user_country_code, $selected_locations, true ) )
        $visible = false;
    else
        $visible = true;
    if( ! $visible || isset( $hidden_items[$item_parent] ) ) { // also hide the children of invisible items
        unset( $items[$key] );
        $hidden_items[$item->ID] = '1';
    }
}

return $items;
}
```